# Converting std::string or string^ to byte array in c++/cli

Tags: .net, string, sockets, c++-cli, tcpclient

I know this is a frequently asked  question and I havent got a clear answer for converting a std::string or String^ to a byte array for writing in to a stream for tcp communication.

This is what I have tried

```
bool CTcpCommunication::WriteBytes(const std::string& rdatastr)
{
  bool retVal = false;

  try
  {
    if (static_cast<NetworkStream^>(stream) != nullptr)
    {
      array<Byte>^data = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(rdatastr); 
      stream->Write( data, 0, data->Length ); 
    }
  }
  catch(Exception^)
  {
    // Ignore, just return false
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

I know that here the GetBytes wont work and I have also checked marshalling options to convert std:string to .NET String but havent found out any.Can someone help me in solving this..

Comment: Marshaling to .NET String, which is well described *everywhere*, has nothing to do with this, you're trying to make a `array<Byte>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encoding is already correct, no conversion needed.  Just copy:

```
array<Byte>^ data = gcnew array<Byte>(rdatastr.size());
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(IntPtr(&rdatastr[0]), data, 0, rdatastr.size());
```

Comment: @ShivShambo: Full type name added.

Comment: ..thanks.. the error now says C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'System::IntPtr'

Comment: @ShivShambo: Oh yeah, stupid BCL and lack of const-correctness.  This edit should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

What about this method:

```
String ^sTemp;
array<Byte> ^TxData;

sTemp = "Hello";
TxData = System::Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(sTemp);
```

Link: http://www.electronic-designer.co.uk/visual-cpp-cli-dot-net/strings/convert-string-to-byte-array

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..Thanks to Ben

```
IntPtr ptr((void*)rdatastr.data());
array<Byte>^ data = gcnew array<Byte>(rdatastr.size()); 
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(ptr, data, 0, rdatastr.size())
```